# PASAR VALOR DE RESULTADO A UN ENLACE

Tags: android

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView etCodigo;
    Button btnEscaner;
    Button ConsultarCodigo;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etCodigo = findViewById(R.id.etCodigo);
        btnEscaner = findViewById(R.id.btnEscaner);

        //ACCION PARA EL BOTON DE ESCANER
        btnEscaner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                escaner();
            }
        });
    }

    //METODO PARA ESCANEAR
    public void escaner(){
        IntentIntegrator intent = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        //intent.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.PRODUCT_CODE_TYPES);
        intent.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
        intent.setPrompt("ESCANEAR CODIGO");
        intent.setCameraId(0);
        intent.setBeepEnabled(true);
        intent.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true);
        intent.setOrientationLocked(false);
        intent.initiateScan();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(result != null){
            if(result.getContents() == null){
                Toast.makeText(this, "SE CANCELO ESCANEO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                etCodigo.setText(result.getContents().toString());

                ConsultarCodigo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ConsultarCodigo);
                ConsultarCodigo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://localhost/consultar_id.php?id="+"VALOR OBTENIDO POR resultgetContents()"));
                        startActivity(browserIntent);

                    }

                });

            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

}
```

tal como indico quiero poner el resultado que da etCodigo.setText(result.getContents().toString()); en el valor del ID. Es posible estoy haciendo bien??? el codigo lo veo en el campo TextView pero necesito utilizarlo tambien como variable para consultar con un boton ese id en el navegador.

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. Tu planteamiento es confuso: *quiero poner el resultado que da etCodigo.setText(result.getContents().toString()); en el valor del ID*... Pues `etCodigo.setText(result.getContents().toString());` no da ningún valor, a lo sumo, el valor lo daría esto: `result.getContents().toString();`, y cuando hablas del `ID` no queda claro a qué te refieres. Si quieres tener el valor en una variable puedes hacer algo así: **`String valorID=result.getContents().toString();`** y luego usarlo donde quieras.

Comment: Creo que lo que me contestas es lo que busco =) voy a probar ahora te digo...

Comment: etCodigo.setText(result.getContents().toString());
                String valorID  =result.getContents().toString();
                ConsultarCodigo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ConsultarCodigo);
                ConsultarCodigo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://localhost/consultar_id.php?id="+valorID));
                        startActivity(browserIntent);

                    }

Comment: no me toma el string me da error soy nuevo en en esto =) agradezco tu ayuda

Comment: Indica en la pregunta qué error da. Además, puede que la variable `valorID` deba ser definida en otra parte, por ejemplo como miembro de la clase (en el caso de que la vayas a usar varios métodos distintos dentro de ella).

Comment: solo lo utilizare para enviar ese valor al hacer click en el boton consultar codigo nada mas. Seria: Uri.parse("localhost/consultar_id.php?id="+valorID));  para concatenar la URL mas la variable verdad?

Comment: Así se concatenan las variables, pero puede que `valorID` no esté en el contexto del click del botón, porque es otro método y no has declarado `valorID` como miembro de la clase... o puede que haya un error en el `Intent`. Si no dices el error que da es más difícil poder ayudarte con precisión.

Comment: Variable valorID is acceced from within inner class, needs to be declared final al posicionarme sobre +valorID

Comment: Correcto. Puedes probar a declarar esa variable como miembro de la clase, haciendo algo así: `private final String valor ID;`, eso debes ponerlo **antes del primer  `@Override`** y cambiar la asignación, poniendo solamente esto: `valorID=result.getContents().toString();`

Comment: private final String valorID; esto no me deja ponerlo en niguna parte dice "not allowed here"

Comment: Prueba a declararla así: `private  String valor_ID="";` antes del primer método de la clase, que supongo que es `onCreate`

Comment: SOS UN MAESTRO!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! funciona a la perfeccion!!!!!!!!!!!! CAPO!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes declarar la variable como miembro de la clase (si necesitas usarla en varias partes de la misma).

Luego, le puedes asignar valor en el método `onCreate` o en otra parte según el caso. Nótese que para dar claridad al código, podrás usar la variable también para el `setText`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Otros  miembros de la clase que ya tienes
    private  final String valor_ID="";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // ... El código que ya tienes ...
        valorID=result.getContents().toString();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        //... código que ya tienes ...
        etCodigo.setText(valorID);   

                    //El onClick sería más o menos así
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        //Mejor una variable url, para más claridad
                        String url="http://localhost/consultar_id.php?id="+valorID;
                        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                        startActivity(browserIntent);

                    }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Voy complicandome mas jajajaj y si ahora quisiera pasar ese String a una activity nueva con un webview? asi no estoy abriendo y cerrando el navegador y me quedo dentro de la misma aplicacion?

Comment: GonzaloRomanValdez cuando empecé con Android intenté usar WebView para mostrar contenido de un sitio remoto en la App, pero WebView me pareció precario, limitado y poco estético, así que opté por un WebService que trae los datos en un JSON (o en HTML) y los muestro en un TextView. Es más elegante y más ligero. En cuanto a pasar info de un sitio a otro, lo puedes hacer enviando extras al Intent. Aquí mismo hay ejemplos de cómo hacerlo.